# .htaccess if request is a file or directory, redirect with absolute path

Tags: .htaccess, relative-path, absolute-path

With this htaccess configuration, I have to set all my .js and .css or image path with absolute path.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

How do I have to modify this htaccess so i can put path of the image, css, or js files doesn't have to be an absolute path?

Is it possible?

Thanks before.

---

**ADD**

Say my directory structure like this:

```
root
-- asset
   -- images
   -- css
   -- js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to just add a relative URI base to your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

But if you must use htaccess, and all of your scripts and styles are in the same place, you can trap it with a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/css
RewriteRule ([^/]+\.css)$ /path/to/css/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/js
RewriteRule ([^/]+\.js)$ /path/to/js/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/images
RewriteRule ([^/]+\.(png|jpe?g|gif))$ /path/to/images/$1 [L,NC]
```

---

EDIT:

if the path to your js/css/images are all in the same place, you can try combining the rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ /assets/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I say thank you for your response. But regex make my brain blows. Can u explain to me about this lines?
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/css
RewriteRule ([^/]+\.css)$ /path/to/css/$1 [L,NC]`
I've add more informations in my question.

Comment: @TikasMamed `!^/path/to/css` means "does NOT start with `/path/to/css`". And `([^/]+\.css)$` means "anything that ends with `<some characters>.css`". Given your dir structure, you'd simply replace `/path/to/` with `/assets/`.

Comment: Why should these lines repeat for js and images? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: @TikasMamed You don't want to rewrite something that already points to a valid resource. Rewrite conditions *only apply to the immediately following rule*, so you need to repeat the conditions you want applied.

Comment: It's sucks because I don't really get this.. How about: if I use ur edited answer and I have `image.jpg` in `asset/images`, my img src attribut should contain just `images/image.jpg`?

Comment: And also how about this line? `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`
Where should I put this?

Comment: @TikasMamed That line, and the 2 rewrite conditions before it needs to go below all of this stuff

Comment: Ah.. finally I get something from this and get a solution for my problem. Thank very much for your patiency to answer all my questions. One more question, what does the `^` sign means?